# Map dataframe values in some columns according to the values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    home_player_1 home_player_2 home_player_3 away_player_1 away_player_2 away_player_3 player_1 ~~~ player_2000
1   23            34             45            2              6               688       0       ~~~  0
2   233           341            4             123            246             678       0       ~~~  0
3   231           234            145           222            6               698       0       ~~~  0
4   235           934            445           1972           16              1688      0       ~~~  0
```

The columns from player_1 to player_2000 are all zero and going to be mapped according to the previous columns. The rule is that the "player_n", where n is a number, representing the number of a player, equals to 1 if the player n appears in any one of the previous 6 columns; otherwise, it is 0.
For example, **the expected output** in the first row is like,

> player_23=player_34=player_45=player_2=player_6=player_688=1, others
> are 0.

**NOTE**: there are no duplicate appearances among the same row.

Comment: kindly post your expected output in the form of a dtaframe just like your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should give you the desired DataFrame:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    values = row[:6]
    for value in values:
        df.at[index, 'player_{}'.format(value)] = 1
```

### **Edit:**

In case you want to avoid iterate over the rows you can use `apply`:

```py
def update_row(row):
    values = row[:6]
    for value in values:
        row.loc['player_{}'.format(value)] = 1
    return row

result_df = df.apply(lambda row: update_row(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: I think so, but I want a speedy one that does not need a nested for loop. I am using a similar idea to yours, which is really computationally demanding.

Comment: @MemphisMeng In case this comment was helpful you can mark it as Accepted